How to fix depth passes vdb issue？

As long as there is a volume object or vdb in the scene, check the Z passes and render, the volume and vdb in the depth passes will have this damaged jagged noise speckled problem, how should I fix this? Tried exr 32bit, increase volume step, change vdb precision to full, still can't solve this problem.The version is blender4.2.

The Z Depth pass is only rendered with 1 sample, so all edges are usually jagged and not anti-aliased. The issue becomes only even more visible on volumetrics since they have no clearly defined boundaries like mesh objects. If you need something more refined and anti-aliased, use the Mist pass.
Z Depth pass:

Mist pass:

But note that none of them will get you real depth information for the volume because therefore it had to be converted into a mesh.

Thank you very much for your help, I finally figured it out, thank you!
